# How to do resolve this? Exporting CSV in Rails 4

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I need export archive CSV in my project. Can anyone help me?

**My controller**

```
 def export
  @travel = Travel.find(params[:id])
  @expense = @travel.expenses
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv 
  end
end
```

**My routes**

```
 resources :travels do
    get 'export' , to: 'travels#export', as: :export
  end
```

**Rake routes**

*travel_export    GET    /travel/:travel_id/export(.:format)            travels#export*

**My link to download**

```
<%= link_to "CSV", travel_export_path(@travel,format: "csv") %>
```

**My travel.rb**

```
class Travel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :expenses

end
```

And finally, my export.csv.rb! I don't know what I need do here.

```
  <%
  headers = [
    "User",
    "Date",
    "Location",
    "Total",
    "Expense",
    "Expense value"



  ]

  csv_output = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << headers

      csv << [
        current_user,
        date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),
        location,
        total        
      ]
      @travel_expenses.each do |expense|
        csv<<[
          expense.typ.description,
          expense.value,
        ]
  end
%>

<%= csv_output.html_safe %>
```

**Please, I need help!**

Comment: My error is : SyntaxError in TravelsController#export

Comment: What line is the error pointing to?

Comment: He not show one line error.

Comment: Could you add the full error message to your question then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one end in export.csv.rb file at the end of @travel_expenses.each